# Rally SDK 2: how to get PortfolioItem/Initiative from user story

Tags: rally

I want to query for user stories and the Initiative that each story falls under. My fetch property looks like:

```
...
model: 'UserStory',
fetch: ['Name', 'PortfolioItem', 'Parent'],
...
```

This fetches the PortfolioItem/Feature object, PortfolioItem/FeatureGroup object but not the PortfolioItem/Initiative. The FeatureGroup object does not show a 'Parent' property.

In short, how can I fetch the parent's parent without querying separately for Initiatives and comparing the '_ref' or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

For server performance reasons the hierarchical relationships will only be populated for one level with each request.  You'll have to make subsequent requests to build the remaining tiers.

Answer (score 0):

If you hit the new Lookback API (unreleased when Kyle first answered, now in open preview), the snapshots returned include a field _ItemHierarchy which will include the ObjectID of all ancestors including all the way up through Portfolio Items.

You can find information on the LBAPI [here](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/). There is support for querying it in the App SDK 2.0's SnapshotStore. Note that SDK 2.0p6 (releasing soon) has some improvements.

Comment: I replaced WsapiDataStore with lookback.SnapshotStore but it errors saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getProxy' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Old, old question.  But I recently did the same thing for the entire tree.  I didn't use the lookback api.  I created a model and stored the data and went through the parentage of each portfolio item.

Perhaps not the most efficient way, but it works.